# Why does HashMap override the existing object when I am returing different hash codes for the same object?

Tags: java, java-8

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map; 

class Geek  
{ 

    public String name; 
    public int id; 

    Geek(String name, int id)  
    { 

        this.name = name; 
        this.id = id; 
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) 
    { 

    // checking if both the object references are  
    // referring to the same object. 
    if(this == obj) 
            return true; 

        // it checks if the argument is of the  
        // type Geek by comparing the classes  
        // of the passed argument and this object. 
        // if(!(obj instanceof Geek)) return false; ---> avoid. 
        if(obj == null || obj.getClass()!= this.getClass()) 
            return false; 

        // type casting of the argument.  
        Geek geek = (Geek) obj; 

        // comparing the state of argument with  
        // the state of 'this' Object. 
        System.out.println("equals method ....."+(geek.name == this.name && geek.id == this.id));
        return (geek.name == this.name && geek.id == this.id); 
    } 

    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() 
    { 

        // We are returning the Geek_id  
        // as a hashcode value. 
        // we can also return some  
        // other calculated value or may 
        // be memory address of the  
        // Object on which it is invoked.  
        // it depends on how you implement  
        // hashCode() method. 
        ++counter;
        System.out.println("counter ::>>> "+counter);
        return counter;
    }
```

Driver code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{ 

    Map<Geek, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    // creating the Objects of Geek class. 
    Geek g1 = new Geek("aa", 1); 
    Geek g2 = new Geek("aa", 1); 


    map.put(g1, g1.id);
    map.put(g2, g2.id);

    map.forEach((k,v) -> {
        System.out.println("key = "+k + "\n value = "+v);
    });

   /* else
    System.out.println("Both Objects are not equal. ");  */
}
```

Here, I am overriding the `hashCode()` method but still the map contains only one object which is `g2`. Why didn't the HashMap store two objects, given that my hashcode returns a different integer every time?

Even though my `equals()` method returns true for the same object, why is the HashMap not storing two objects? Can someone please guide me in this regard?

Comment: Although your `hashCode` method in this case actually does return the same hash code for separate objects, it's not impossible for `HashMap` to use `equals` to compare objects of different hash codes, if the objects should happen to land in the same hash table bucket. You're deliberately trying to break the map here, so you shouldn't expect logical behavior.

Answer (score 7):

Your `counter` variable is an instance variable, so it's initialized to `0` for each `Geek` instance. Therefore, both `g1` and `g2` have the same `hashCode()` of `1` when you put them in the `Map`, and are considered identical by the `HashMap`, since they are equal to each other based on your `equals` implementation.

If you change `counter` to be `static`, you will get different `hashCode()` for the 2 instances of `Geek`, and they would be stored in separate map entries.

That said, your `hashCode()` implementation is very bad. If you call `hashCode()` for the same instance multiple times, you'll get a different result each time! This means that if you attempt to put `g1` twice in the `Map`, it will probably put it twice, since the second `put` will see a different `hashCode()`, and will therefore search for the key in a different bucket.

Comment: you didn't get my question. Try and understand it what i am asking you. Don't tell me the contract of equals() and hashcode. I know it very well. what i am trying to ask is - why hashmap didnot store 2 objects ?

Comment: @Vikasnaik did you intend to post this comment under one of the other answers? I didn't tell you the contract of equals and hashcode.

Comment: @Vikasnaik As I explained, `hashCode()` returns `1` for both instances of `Geek` (at the first time hashCode is called for both of those instances). Hence the `HashMap` stores them both in the same bucket, and since they are equal, the second overrides the first.

Comment: @Vikasnaik perhaps you should replace `map.put(g1, g1.id); map.put(g2, g2.id);` with `System.out.println(g1.hashCode()); System.out.println(g2.hashCode());`  to better understand my answer.

Comment: It must be emphasize that this touches implementation dependent behavior, so even if the two objects did return different hash codes, there is no guaranty that the `HashMap` does not call `equals` on them (and hence notice their equality).

Comment: @Holger if the hash map sees different hash codes for two objects it will not compare them using `equals`. Only if it sees the same hash codes will it further test using `equals`. This is why changing the hash code for an item in a hash map is bad, because the search will no longer find it and it will never use `equals` to fix that.

Comment: @LewBloch this is not a guaranteed behavior. Using hash codes is a performance optimization, nothing more. You are required to keep hashCode and equals in sync, so that it doesn’t matter whether it uses the hash code or not.

Comment: You are correct, however the probability that the implementation of `HashMap` in use uses a hash map is near certainty. To code as if it won't happen is not good; on that we clearly agree.

Answer (score 1):

`hashCode()` function must not change when you call it on the same object instance multiple times. You can't generate a new value each time you call it, right now you are doing it by incrementing counter.

As per [`Object.hashCode()` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()):

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.

Comment: While this is correct, it doesn't explain the behavior the OP encountered.

Comment: you didn't get my question. Try and understand it what i am asking you. Don't tell me the contract of equals() and hashcode. I know it very well. what i am trying to ask is - why hashmap didnot store 2 objects ?